# JS JQuery Bootstrap datatables resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a datatable that displays 10 columns but the problem is it dont fit the screen properly. I still need to scroll horizontally and vertically to see the other columns/rows. What I want to do is to make the table smaller. How can I achieve that? Refer to the screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L91JR.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrcl9.png) . I have tried setting table width = "100%" but unfortunately nothing happens.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">

    <center><h1 class="page-header">TMTRO Iloilo <small>Violators Records</small> </h1></center>

    <div class="removeMessages"></div>

    <button class="btn btn-default pull pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMember" id="addMemberModalBtn">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Member
    </button>

    <br /> <br /> <br />

    <table class="table-striped table-bordered nowrap" width="100%" id="manageMemberTable">     
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>ID #</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>License Number</th>
       <th>Violation</th>
       <th>Arrest Place</th>            
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Plate Number</th>
       <th>Contact Number</th>
       <th>Officer Name</th>
       <th>Date&Time</th>       
       <th>Paid</th>
       <th>Option</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It is the very disadvantage of using HTML `<table>` as table elements have this weird `Cell min-width` feature which when it comes to that point the cell stops from resizing forcing the table to go out of the view. To make the table fit at your desired width, make the `text smaller` or remove columns you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html), a `<table>` and its children are auto-sized. Put simply, other rules are thrown out the window to make the table itself look good, by default.

Bootstrap does have an answer for this, with [responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables). Just add the `table-responsive` class to your table element and it'll handle any scrollbars within the table rather than allowing your entire page to scroll.

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  ...
</table>
```